# Having a fixed menu for some of my Views in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to have a fix menu on some of my views. For example I have a view called 'Kitchen' and then I have sub views in there. I need to have a fix menu to each view there.

I have been able to menu to each view file but how do I make a separate file for menu on some particular views. I am using razor as template engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use a different shared template (like `...\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml`) for the views that need a menu. This template can itself use another (like `...\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml`) for content common with all pages. So this my setting `Layout` to the relative path to the template.
2. Use a partial view: another Razor file that is included into the views are renders the menu:

   ```
   @Html.Partial("_TheMenu", menuModel)
   ```

   the model parameter, if no model needed, isn't requited.